# How to turn off ag-grid quick filter for specific column

Tags: filter, ag-grid

AG-grid has ["quick filter"](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-quick/) feature, essentially a free-text search filter that searches through all columns.
The problem is, in some columns, I have date-time values and I don't want to search through data in those columns.

Using "column filter" to filter on each column separately is not an option because this will give me "AND" behavior: only when all columns that I search through contain the data I search for will this column be visible. And I need "OR" behavior: a row that contains the data I search for in any column (except column that has date-time values) should be visible.

So, how can I remove some columns from the set of columns this "quick filter" searches through?

Answer (score 13):

I just needed to set an "empty" function as "getQuickFilterText" function for the column I don't want to search through:

```
colDef = {
    getQuickFilterText: () => ''
}
```

Comment: added this in default column defs in the definition of the grid, where I included  if (hdr.attribute === 'col_name') { col = { ...col, getQuickFilterText: (params) => params.value }} for the columns that I needed to include
        }