# Adding Search box outside ag-grid

Tags: search, ag-grid

I look at this example, this allows to search for all columns.  How to I searrch for either two columns only? E.g. I want to search Name or Country? Is using api.getSelectedNodes() and filter, the best way to do the search?

https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php#/

Comment: Are you using any frameworks in particular? React, Angular?

Comment: Hi @wentjun I'm using React framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say the best solution would be to set an empty value for the search value for each of the columns you do not want to search through:

```
colDef = {
    getQuickFilterText: () => ''
}
```

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52041955/how-to-turn-off-ag-grid-quick-filter-for-specific-column) questions.

More documentation can also be found [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-quick/)

Comment: Interesting :). Thanks